# Auto generated key in Ant Design Upload react component causes snapshot test to fail

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd

I am using the Upload ant design component, and its working well except it generates a file input with an auto generated key. Every time I run the tests, a new key is generated, so the snapshot don't match and my test fails.

Setting the key on the Upload doesn't affect the input key, so I have no evident way to mock this. I also tried using the new property matchers, but all the examples I found were very simple, using one simple object, couldn't figure out how to use with a wrapper containing many nested react components.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to deal with ant design auto generated keys... Any help or pointing in the right direction would be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using Enzyme and Jest with snapshot testing:

```js
describe('<Uploader />', () => {
  test('it renders', () => {
    const uploaderProps = {
      accept: 'application/pdf,image/*',
      action: 'https://file-service.example.com/v1/upload',
      defaultFileList: [
        {
          uid: '1',
          name: 'under-construction.gif',
          status: 'done',
          url: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/EIiJp9cQ3GeEU/giphy.gif',
          thumbUrl: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/EIiJp9cQ3GeEU/giphy.gif',
        },
      ],
      multiple: true,
      name: 'file-input',
      onChange: jest.fn(),
    };
    const uploader = mount(<Uploader {...uploaderProps} />);
    expect(uploader.render()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Note the use of `.render()` to generate the snapshot without the key.